# Using a different SSL certificate for different domains in CloudFront distribution?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have a CloudFront distribution which I'm using to serve static files (images etc) on my website. As of today it uses the default `foo.cloudfront.net` domain (with Amazon's free, built-in SSL certificate).

I want to switch this distribution over to a "real" domain that's part of my site (eg. `media.mysite.com`). As soon I make this change in CloudFront (eg. switch from its Default CloudFront Certificate to my own `*.mysite.com` cert), **will this break my existing files being served over `https://foo.cloudfront.net`**?

If this is the case then I'll need to somehow switch all the image sources on my site over to the new domain at the same time as enabling the custom SSL certificate for the distribution, which will be tricky.

On the other hand, reading [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/cnames-https-dedicated-ip-or-sni.html) suggests that CloudFront might be doing some work to determine which certificate to use:

> CloudFront uses the IP address to identify your distribution and to determine which SSL/TLS certificate to return to the viewer.

... possibly?

Does anyone have any experience with this sort of changeover, or is there a better way to switch domains without having to change a non-trivial amount of URL references simultaneously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood the concern,

1. Your CloudFront URL `https://foo.cloudfront.net` will work after a switch to `media.mysite.com`.
2. All you need to do is add a CNAME `foo.cloudfront.net` to domain `media.mysite.com` & define `media.mysite.com` as CNAME in cloudfront distribution settings. Also, add your cutom SSL certificate to the distribution.
3. No, it won't break any of your contents until & unless you have hardcoded some dependency to the Cloudfront URL. Such as the requests Origin should be the Cloudfront URL etc.

CloudFront uses the IP address to identify your distribution and to determine which SSL/TLS certificate to return to the viewer.

**Answer -** 
This happens only if you have opted for Dedicated IP which means you want to serve all the users including the clients which doesn't support SNI.
Below is what happens when you use SNI & not a dedicated IP -

`When CloudFront receives the request, it finds the domain name in the request header and responds to the request with the applicable SSL/TLS certificate.`

[image]

I guess you have not opted for a dedicated IP.

PS - I did this yesterday & it went smooth. It takes some time for Cloudfront deployment on Edge locations, be patient. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you – I can confirm that this worked (eg. when I changed this to use my custom SSL cert, it served the Cloudfront one when I requested `foo.cloudfront.net` and my own cert when I accessed it via `mysite.com`).